# Building ROS1 packages with colcon

Tags: ros, ros2, build-package, devel

I'm trying to build the old [rosaria](https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria) package in my ROS2 (Iron Irwini) workspace, but currently encountering an issue during compilation.
I've successfully built ROS2 and `ros1_bridge` from source as per the [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Using-ros1_bridge-Jammy-upstream.html) (in separate workspaces), but when trying to build rosaria (on a new workspace, sourcing the ROS2 setup.bash), I get:

```
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'iron' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
```

Per the official [official docs](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/quick-start.html#build-ros-1-packages), `colcon build` should be able to compile ROS1 packages, but apparently catkin (which is used as the build tool) fatally complains about incompatible ROS2 versions.

Is there a way to make the build process ignore the `ROS_DISTRO` environment variables?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! earlier, while migrating from ROS 1 to ROS 2, I used [ros1_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge) for some packages. It worked as expected. However, I am unsure what you are trying to achieve in this question. Do you want to use `colcon` instead of `catkin` to build a ROS 1 package? OR do you want to use your ROS 1 package in ROS 2?

Comment: @ravi this package isn't mine, I just want to use it, but naturally I need to build it first. SInce I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, I can't install a full ROS1 distribution, but as I've linked to in the question `colcon` should be able to build the package.

Comment: I see. You want to use `ros1_bridge` but don't have complete ROS 1 distro. As a workaround, you can use ROS 1 inside docker though.